# How can i override the default size of input in @emotion/styled (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, next.js, emotion

How can I override the default size props?
I wanna change it to "md" | "lg".

```
interface InputProps {
    size?: keyof typeof theme.padding.rect; // "md" | "lg"
}

const Input = styled.input<InputProps>(({theme, size}) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.colors.dark.background.primary,
  border: theme.colors.dark.border,
  borderRadius: theme.borderRadius,
  padding: theme.padding.rect[size], // size: undefined
}))
```

Comment: Are you getting an error when trying to do this?

Comment: no, nothing error on development. However, it will cause an error at compile time.

Comment: For this case, we can work around this by adding [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like `padding: theme.padding.rect[size as any as keyof typeof theme.padding.rect]`. The next problem is when we want to specify a value for size at the time of component call